# Java EE 6 CDI injecting provider

Tags: java, cdi, provider

I have doubts on when to inject the provider of an interface and when to inject an interface directly.

1. What is the appropriate situation where a provider should be used? Please give examples.
2. If the scope of an interface is `@Dependant`, then the injector will create a new object anyway, if so then do we still need to use a provider?
3. If `@New` is used, a new object is created. Do we need a provider then?

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reasons to use providers (you don't inject providers though) is to do some configuration of a class. Another good reason is if the class isn't available as a CDI bean.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your second point, however not the first one. Can you give examples?

Comment: Say you need to call a setter or some other configuration, maybe the class you produce is only available via a factory of builder.